# How to logged in with session in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am a newbie in laravel. I made a registration and logged in form. The user can register himself but I am unable to create logged in form appropriately. I want to able the user to logged in with session on correct information of username and password.

here is my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Auth;

class tuto extends Controller
{
    public function login(){
        return view('pages.login');
    }

    public function login_validation(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
    'username' => 'required|min:3|max:10',
     'password' => 'required|min:6',

    ]);

    if(Auth::attempt(['name'=>$request->username,'password'=>$request->password])){
        return "true";
        }

    return 'false';
    }

}
```

I am getting false message even on correct username and password. here is my logged in page:

```
<form method="POST" action="/login" autocomplete="off">

        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="form-group" align="center">
            <button class="btn btn-success">LogIn</button>

        </div>
        <div align="center"> Don't have an account ?  <a href="/register"> SignUp </a> </div>

</form>
```

also I want to create session on successful authentication. any help would be highly appreciable. Thank you

Comment: Laravel has a builtin registration and login function you can enable. Use that to avoid all this problems

Comment: as I mentioned that i am newbie and learning laravel so I want to do some custom work to get expertise on laravel.

Comment: I would suggest opting out of the authentication and doing your custom practice on a different module instead. Maybe creating blog posts that still uses sessions. For the authentication check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIRzJgxhgYo)

Comment: ok. but how can I get build in logged in function ?

Comment: You can check the video I posted on a detailed guide on how to do it. there's also an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid these kind of errors. Use laravel's build-in authentication system.

1.create new laravel app `laravel new my-project`

2.cd into `my-project` and type `php artisan make:auth`

This will create a basic authentication system with all login and registration routes, controllers and views

Comment: is it necessary on make new laravel app ?? what about If I work on my existing app and run that command php artisan make:auth

Comment: I would suggest removing your login codes first before running that command as it might cause some duplicate filename problems.

Answer (score 1):

laravel `attempt`, automatically create the session if the username and password correct, so instead of returning true just redirecting user to his dashboards.
you also must create the post route in web.php for that `login_validation` method.
hope is work.

sorry, my speaking english is very weak.